# Download a file in resource folder of spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to download a file from a URL then unzip it into the resources folder of a spring boot project.

If I use location of resources folder eg: /src/main/resources/ , it gets downloaded in resources folder but it does not work after we package and run the JAR file.

Please help

Comment: Why unzip it? Use it as a dependency and then it's on the class path?

Comment: Some more details would be helpful. When you say "download a file and unzip" what do you mean? Your code has a feature that donwloads a zip file and unzips it in a specific folder?

Comment: I need to download a file from a link , I get it in a zip format then using zip4j library I unzip it and provide location where it is to be extracted. What I want is that file to be on the classpath, how can we achieve that.